# Audio stream interfacing API's, Tokbox and Twilio

Tags: audio, twilio, opentok, tokbox

Hi so we have a brain teaser on our hands.

Currently we're attempting to build a conferencing application with Tokbox, the setup is simple and the video conferencing works fine.

However we want to be able to break into voice, so this means if user x and y are video conferencing but user Z doesn't have a computer they can dial in via a twilio phone number, however the issues comes with the audio, we need the twilio audio to be layered into the tokbox audio so everybody can hear each other.

The best solution is to turn off the tokbox audio and let the twilio client handle the audio, via posting tokbox audio through their client, however this seems it would be a slow option.

Ideally tokbox would be able to handle the twilio audio but it currently doesn't have support.

Apart from extending tokbox with a lot of custom code I was just wandering if you guys know anyway of mixing audio into one layer?

Answer (score 0):

With OpenTok's new [iOS v2.2 beta](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/) or [Android v2.2 beta](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/android/) there is an included tutorial that lets you build your own Publisher object so that you can stream your own media (pictures, videos from your phone, etc). You might be able to build you own Publisher object to steam Twilio's audio.